# The Force of Gravitational Waves

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, orbital-motion, gravitational-waves

How could one calculate and derive the "force" or displacement and stretching of an object due to gravitational waves?

Comment: try searching on "LIGO".

Comment: [*Gravitational Waves Volume 1* by Maggiore](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198570745.001.0001/acprof-9780198570745) contains the calculations you're looking for, as well as many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the locally inertial frame of the particles, you can write the motion in terms of the *Riemann curvature tensor* (evaluated at the origin) as
\begin{equation}
\frac{{\rm d^2} x^i}{{\rm d} t^2} = - R^0_{\ i0j}(0) x^j
\end{equation}
where $x^i$ is the distance of the particle from the origin in the $i$-\th direction (note that by using locally inertial coordinates, we are assuming $x^i$ is small, compared to the length scale associated with the curvature, which in this case will mean the wavelength of the gravitational wave).

For a monochromatic gravitational plane wave with frequency $f$, (in units with $c=1$, and apologies if I have lost track of a factor of 2)
\begin{equation}
R^0_{\ i0j}(0) = \omega^2 \left(h_+ e^+_{ij} + h_\times e^\times_{ij}\right) \sin \omega t
\end{equation}
where the sum over $j$ is assumed, $\omega=2\pi f$ is the angular frequency, $h_+$ is the amplitude of the "plus" gravitational-wave polarization, and $h_\times$ is the amplitude of the "times" gravitational-wave polarization, and $e^+$ and $e^\times$ are symmetric and trace-free "polarization tensors" which capture the motion of the particles. If we let the $z$ axis be the direction of propagation of the gravitational wave, we can choose coordinates in the $x-y$ plane such that
\begin{equation}
e^+ = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right), \ e^\times =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation}
If you imagine a ring of particles, purely "plus" motion will cause particles along the $x$ axis to increase their distance from the origin while particles along the $y$ axis will increase their distance. If you think about it and draw some pictures, you can also convince yourself that the "cross" polarization will cause a cross motion. Here are some pictures from [the Living Reviews article "The Confrontation between General Relativity and Experiment
" by Cliff Will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave):

[image]

Coming back to the equation, we can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{{\rm d}^2 x^i}{{\rm d} t^2} = - \omega^2 \left(\sum_{a=+,\times} h_a e^a_{ij}\right) x^j
\end{equation}
Assuming all the masses are the same for simplicity, this is equivalent to a set of coupled harmonic oscillators
\begin{equation}
m \frac{{\rm d^2} x_i}{{\rm d} t^2} = F_i = - K_{ij} x^j
\end{equation}
where $F_i$ is the force, and where the "coupling matrix" $K_{ij}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
K_{ij} = m \omega^2 \sum_{a=+,\times} h_a e^a_{ij}
\end{equation}

Comment: thanks this works